# How to keep AlarmManager to start Service after kill my app?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I need to request a url every 5 seconds.So I used `AlarmManager` to send a intent by call `setRepeating`.but when I long click HOME hardware button to kill it, AlarmManager doesn't work. How to solve that? :)

Comment: You can't... Application kill means user doesn't want to use app (forever or for sort time). So only one solution is that re-schedule Alarm on launch of application...

Comment: umm....but why the system's alarm app can run all the time,when I set alarm by system's alarm app,and return HOME screen, long click HOME, I can see that app in recent list ,and `claer all`.the system alarm will run on time that I set.@PankajKumar

Comment: Kill alarm from application manager and then check.

Comment: you can make a service and then use AlarmManager.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if you don't kill your Alarm when you call the onDestroy(), the Alarm should still be running on background even after application exit. Are you sure that you are not terminating it somewhere inside your onDestroy() method?

If you give a look here :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

The docs says : "The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, **even if your application is not currently running.** For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler."

Remember that if your phone is in stand-by it might not be able to execute the code you want to, you need to wake it up properly.

Comment: Thank you, and I will try more.